# BlobTrigger blobpath binding is not working properly

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, azure-blob-storage

I have two containers in my blob storage called "images" and "images2". I'm trying to have a trigger bond to "images2" container. I believe this should do the job:

```
public static void ResizeImagesTask(
    [BlobTrigger("images2/{name}.{ext}")] Stream inputBlob ,
    string name,
    string ext,
    IBinder binder)
```

To my surprise, the function triggered by blobs stored in "images" container as well which leads to an error.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the function triggered by blobs stored in "images" container as well which leads to an error.

Did you use "images" as the container name in the same function and the error occurred after you changed the container name to "images2"? If yes, the error might cause the blob trigger cache. Azure WebJobs will save WebJob runtime data and history data in azure-webjobs-hosts container. We can check this container in Azure Storage Explorer.

[image]

If you changed some properties of your function, I suggest you clear the related information of your function in this container. For example, delete the folder with the same name of your function under blobreceipts and blobscaninfo folder.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @amor-msft. That was the case.